# Syntax Error using IN-clause in an UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use a query builder to generate some SQL for multiple dialects.

Following query is giving me an error and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.OBJECT SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' WHERE dbo.OBJECT."OBJEC_ID" IN (69, 42, 1337)
```

> Error #46010 on line 1, column 66: Incorrect syntax near "OBJEC_ID".

"OBJEC_ID" is in quotes because some columns were named after existing keywords in some dialects, so it should stay that way.

I already tried to quote and unquote the table specifiers, remove them. It "works" if I remove the WHERE clause so it is definitely in there.

EDIT: I don't have the exact CREATE TABLE command but here is a screenshot of all the column defintions (bold fields are required):

[image]

EDIT 2: There are triggers on the table but only on updating some timestamps. There are for sure no triggers on "LANGNAME". It is also not a unique field. This is the rest I know about the table:

[image]

Comment: Please share `dbo.OBJECT ` definition (`CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: you can write only the name of column in where condition like `UPDATE dbo.OBJECT SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' WHERE OBJEC_ID IN (69, 42, 1337)` i tested this syntax on adventurework2017

Comment: Do you have any triggers on that table? There is something cause the error you don't tell us about it, although your query is fine. Also, it seems to me that SQL Server won't specify `column 66` in the error message. The error message would be like `Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 6`

Comment: The picture you just share is for `INDEX`es not `TRIGGER`s. And since you state that there is triggers on the table, then the error comes from there for sure or the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets instead:

```
UPDATE dbo.OBJECT 
SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' 
WHERE dbo.OBJECT.[OBJEC_ID] IN (69, 42, 1337)
```

Or if your column name really contains quotation marks, include them as well:

```
UPDATE dbo.OBJECT 
SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' 
WHERE dbo.OBJECT.["OBJEC_ID"] IN (69, 42, 1337)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7d6b/1).

Comment: Thanks for the info on that you can do that, but it doesn't solve the problem. OBJEC_ID is not a reserved word, yet it still errors at that point. I tested it with brackets but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: There is something else that is causing the error? See the SQLFiddle. Where do you run the command from?

Comment: The issue was actually the tool I used for testing not functioning properly. I have no parsing errors with this method anymore. Sorry for the confusion and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 UPDATE a
    SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' 
    from dbo.OBJECT a  WHERE a."OBJEC_ID" IN (69, 42, 1337)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution. use square brackets instead of quotes like `dbo.OBJECT.[OBJEC_ID]` instead of `dbo.OBJECT."OBJEC_ID"`.

```
UPDATE dbo.OBJECT SET LANGNAME = 'FooBar' WHERE dbo.OBJECT.[OBJEC_ID] IN (69, 42, 1337)
```